# Como fazer um Content Script se comunicar com elemento iFrame em extensão para o Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, google-chrome-extensão

Eu desenvolvi uma toolbar para o Google Chrome, adicionando-a ás páginas através de um iFrame:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.id="iframeId";
iframe.src = chrome.extension.getURL('CLAWS_Sem_Imagens.html');
iframe.style.height = 7em;
iframe.style.width = '100%';
iframe.style.position = 'fixed';
iframe.style.top = '0';
iframe.style.left = '0';
iframe.style.zIndex = '938089'; 
//other stuff

document.documentElement.insertBefore(iframe,document.body); 

// pulling down the rest of the page
var bodyStyle = document.body.style;
var cssTransform = 'transform' in bodyStyle ? 'transform' : 'webkitTransform';
bodyStyle[cssTransform] = 'translateY(' + height + ')';
```

O que eu preciso é que, quando o usuário selecionar uma palavra na página principal, ela seja armazenada em uma variável (ou elemento HTML) que está dentro desse iFrame (lógica já implementada). **Portanto, eu preciso que o content-script e o toolbar se comuniquem** (o primeiro reconhece que a palavra foi selecionada e a armazena em uma variável/elemento do segundo).

Para fins de teste, estou tentando fazer com que o content-script reconheça a existência de um span dentro do iframe:

```
  <span id="palavra">
  Palavra       
  </span>
```

Eu já tentei usar `iframe.contentDocument.getElementById("palavra")`, `window.document.getElementById("iframeId").contentWindow.querySelector("#palavra")` e `window.frames['iframeId'].contentDocument.getElementById('palavra')`, mas nada funciona. Alguma sugestão?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que deu a entender de sua pergunta, você precisa pegar o evento de seleção de texto em qualquer lugar da tela, e salvar esse valor em uma variável dentro de sua extensão. Se for realmente isto o código abaixo resolve seu problema, se não for explique a situação nos comentários que reformulo a resposta :D

Para chrome extension ficaria algo assim:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {method: "getSelection"}, function(response){
     setarConteudoSelecionado(response.data);
  });
});

function setarConteudoSelecionado(selectedText) {
  //seta conteudo na sua variavel :D
}
```

Em JavaScript puro a ideia seria essa:

```
//declaro variavel para guardar seu texto
var textoSelecionado = '';

/*pega todos eventos de click, lembrando que 
o evento de click ele é trigado quando o botão é solto.
*/
document.body.addEventListener('click', pegarTexto, true);

/*metodo chamado pela função de click*/
function pegarTexto() {

    /*busca todos os texto selecionados na tela*/
    var selecionado = window.getSelection().toString();

    /*verifica se o evento é de seleção*/
    if (selecionado) {
        /*seta na sua variavel que deve estar na sua extensão*/
        textoSelecionado = selecionado;
        document.getElementById('ultimoTexto').innerHTML = selecionado;
    }
}
```

Segue o [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/32wvv8ak/).

Comment: Muito obrigado por responder! De fato, o seu código me será de grande utilidade! Porém...o meu problema principal não é exatamente esse, mas sim a parte que você comentou "seta conteudo na sua variavel".O problema é que eu estou em um content_script, e a minha variável está dentro de um iframe que eu adiciono ás páginas (através desse content script), e eu não estou conseguindo acessar o conteúdo interno desse iframe. Vou colocar um desenho tosco na postagem pra tentar explicar melhor.

Comment: @MrGuliarte agora entendi seu problema hehe .. chegando em casa eu tento algo para te ajudar :DD

Comment: Cara, não tenho como agradecer!

Comment: @MrGuliarte você chegou a ver isso ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325415/access-iframe-content-from-a-chromes-extension-content-script está em inglês, se tiver algum problema me avise que abstraio aqui pra você :D

Comment: Cara, vi este link ontem! Mau não ter respondido antes! Mas ele solucionou meu problema sim, vlw : D